# jQuery - find table row containing table cell containing specific text

Tags: jquery, dom

I need to get a `tr` element which contains a `td` element which contains specific text. The `td` will contain that text and only that text (so I need `text = 'foo'` not `text contains 'foo'` logic).

So I need the equivalent of the following 'pseudo jQuery':

```
var tableRow = $(table td[text = 'foo']).parent('tr');
```

Can anyone provide the correct syntax?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do that:

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "foo";
}).closest("tr");
```

Comment: Also checkout @pi answer below for a more recent approach

Comment: @TFD, that approach is a little different, as `contains()` matches substrings -- it would match elements whose text is `foobar`, for instance, not only `foo`.

Answer (score 59):

I know this is an old post but I thought I could share an alternative [not as robust, but simpler] approach to searching for a string in a table.

`$("tr:contains(needle)");` //where needle is the text you are searching for.

For example, if you are searching for the text 'box', that would be:

```
$("tr:contains('box')");
```

This would return all the elements with this text. Additional criteria could be used to narrow it down if it returns multiple elements

Comment: This solution would contain ANY tr that contains that. So if you have a table within a table within.. (etc.) then it will pick the top tr and hide everything under it, but OP wants the closest tr.

Comment: You can also do `$("td:contains('box')");` to get the exact column where the text was found.

Answer (score 19):

```
$(function(){
    var search = 'foo';
    $("table tr td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == search;
    }).parent('tr').css('color','red');
});
```

Will turn the text red for rows which have a cell whose text is 'foo'.

Answer (score 2):

This will search text in all the td's inside each tr and show/hide tr's based on search text

```
 $.each($(".table tbody").find("tr"), function () {                              

                if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').indexOf(searchText.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()) == -1)
                    $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <input type="text" id="text" name="search">
<table id="table_data">
        <tr class="listR"><td>PHP</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>MySql</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>AJAX</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>jQuery</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>JavaScript</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>HTML</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>CSS</td></tr>
        <tr class="listR"><td>CSS3</td></tr>
</table>

$("#textbox").on('keyup',function(){
        var f = $(this).val();
      $("#table_data tr.listR").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(f, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
             } else {
                 $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

[Demo](http://qaify.com/how-to-implement-text-searching-on-table-rows-in-jquery/)
You can perform by search() method with use RegExp matching text