# jQuery : find table row containing two cells that have specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with two columns for codes.I named them `Main Code` and `Sub Code`. I have 2 text box for **search** in table that I want when user fill up them and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, change `background-color` of the row that contain `Main Code` and `Sub Code` . I see this topic :

[find table row containing table cell containing specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135665/jquery-find-table-row-containing-table-cell-containing-specific-text)

but it don't know how to check 2 cell instead of one cell.please help me

thanks

**Edit 1)**

this is an example of my table:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 400px; text-align: center;">
    <tr style="background-color:Aqua">
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Main Code</th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Sub Code</th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            ID</th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
            Desc</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            10000</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            454</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            some Desc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            10000</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            2</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            123</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            10001</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            1</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            454</td>
        <td style="width: 25%">
            some</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    searchTerm1 = $('input.maincode').val();
    searchTerm2 = $('input.subcode').val();
    $("td:contains("+searchTerm1+")")
        .siblings()
        .filter(":contains("+searchTerm2+")").parent('tr').css('background','yellow');
```

Comment: that's not answer to my question. I want to search in my table

Comment: Oh! Sorry, do you want to search the main code and sub code columns on the basis of two input texts one of which takes main code text and the other takes sub code text?

Comment: Edited my answer, it's the base idea, should be improved by introducing filter to search only the main code and sub code columns

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JrrDn/47/

The code might be a little messy but the concept holds. Basically you want to iternate through each tr and check if the nth-child(1) and nth-child(2) are the values you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery for this:

```
 $('table th:contains("Main Code")').parent().css('background-color', 'red'); 
 $('table th:contains("Sub Code")').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: oh my god... I want to search 10000 and 1 not  `main code` text and `sub code` text :-? . I want search in my table

Comment: Hey man, check first 3 lines of your question's body. Anyways, in that case you simply have to change Main Code/Sub Code with 10000/1.