# Searching a table row for specific text in a COLUMN with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I found  [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135665/jquery-find-table-row-containing-table-cell-containing-specific-text) that has a very nice answer, but being a beginner, I want a more detailed explanation, because my situation is a bit different: I have a table like the one below:

```
 ________________________________________________
 | id |     name     | age |      location      |
 |----+--------------+-----+--------------------|
 |  1 | Victor       | 14  | Bucharest, Romania |
 |  2 | John         | 17  | New York, USA      |
 |  3 | Steve        | 12  | New York, USA      |
 |  7 | Michael      | 37  | Washington DC, USA |
 |  9 | Michaela     | 25  | Washington DC, USA |
 |----+--------------+-----+--------------------|
```

The id of the person is in my database (MySQL database) set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so if I delete a record, it will be like the last one in my table here (from 7 to 9). I want to search the row that has the `personId = 3` in my HTML table.

So, based on [the question in my link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135665/jquery-find-table-row-containing-table-cell-containing-specific-text), how can I refine that search to be only in the ID column?

Edit for @yeyene:

This is the function based on your code. Actually, I don't need to change the background color of the row, I need the row's index for using it later with `.eq(index)` to make some operations on it:

```
function findTableRow(personId){
    $('#people tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == personId){
            return (row's index?)
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: How about you show us your code and what you have already tried doing?

Comment: From Wikipedia: `jQuery is a multi-browser (cf. cross-browser) JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML.` jQuery is not for querying databases. The link you post refers to an HTML table not a database table.

Comment: I am also refering to an HTML table @Matt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check here, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wAxNu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == '3'){
            $(this).css('background','red');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: please, take a look at my edit. actually it is my fault, I should have explained my situation briefly for you to give a good answer :)

Comment: with your code, I only need to add `return $(this).index()` thanks

Comment: Any shorter version of this? seems `:contains()` does not work for such kind of work.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that with your database query:

```
SELECT (id, name, age, location) FROM table WHERE id = 3;
```

If you want to use filters on page, you can you the first answer of your posted question:

```
var tableRow = $("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "3";
}).closest("tr");
```

Explanation:

1. Make a `var tableRow`
2. Find all cells with `$("td")`
3. Filter the found cells based on a function, this is testing whether the content of the cell is equal to '3'. `$(this)` refers to the cell, `.text()` outputs the text content.
4. `closest("tr")` is added to select the `tr` where the `td` is placed in.
5. If you want to do something with that row, you can do this: `tablerow.hide()`.

To hide all rows, but not the selected row, use this code:

```
$('tr').not(tableRow).hide();
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hzW2a/

Comment: I cannot achieve that with my database query, because I need to add a class on that found row :)