# JQuery Get content of cells on same row

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an issue very similar to what was asked on [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135665/jquery-find-table-row-containing-table-cell-containing-specific-text), but the syntax is a little different. I'm pretty sure it's a minor tweak but have spent too much time trying. Any help would be appreciated.

I am trying to pass the contents of selected row cells from a Telerik GV. The "path" variable is passed through a partial view, I cannot use "this" as it is not run directly from a click event. My issue is the var t3 returns the concatenated contents of ALL the rows contents for that column : "Test Deschi ho hi whatevah". How can I modify this to only give me the cell contents of the row with the matching span id? Thank you in advance.

```
<tr>
 <td><input id="..." value="Accounting-Payroll" type="checkbox"></td>
 <td><span id="Accounting-Payroll_span">Accounting-Payroll</span></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>Test Desc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input value="Advertising and Marketing" type="checkbox"></td>
 <td><span id="Advertising and Marketing_span">Advertising and Marketing</span></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input id="..." value="TestAccessFile600.pdf" type="checkbox"></td>
 <td><span id="TestAccessFile600.pdf_span" style="padding-left: 2px;"> TestAccessFile600.pdf</span></td>
 <td>Title for test access file yada</td>
 <td>hi ho hi whatevah</td>
</tr>

    var path='TestAccessFile600.pdf';

    function EditFile(path) {
    var trw = $("td").filter(function () {
        return  $('span#' + path + '_span')}).closest("tr");
    var t3 = trw.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    ...
}
```

I created a fiddle (my first): [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spxdypck/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function EditFile(path) {
    var trw = $('span#' + path.replace(".", "\\.") + '_span').parent().parent();
    var t3 = trw.find('td:eq(3)').text();
    ...
}
```

See fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mLvhhgcc/

Comment: thanx for the reply, but this returns null. I updated the question with a fiddle

Comment: Ah yes... you need to escape the dot `.`. See update

Comment: When I added a more complex path such as "C:/Webs/DMS/Company/TestAccessFile600.pdf" I had to modify it a bit. I am posting it hear in case it helps someone else:   https://jsfiddle.net/r8ddbsqy/