# jQuery - find text in table and match against variable

Tags: jquery

I want to see if a product title appears in a table:

Product title HTML:

```
<h1 class="font-product-title">220 foo string</h1>
```

Simplified HTML table:

```
<table class="waffle">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><div>1</div></th>
      <td><div>220 foo string</div></td>
      <td>£17.98</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th><div>2</div></th>
      <td><div>330 foo string</div></td>
      <td>£18.98</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, my code is always returning true:

```
//First create a variable of the product title
var matchTitle = $('h1.font-product-title').text();

//Double check the element is targeting correctly
console.log(matchTitle);

if ( $("table.waffle td div:contains(matchTitle)") ) {
    console.log('Title is located in imported data');
}   
else {
    console.log('Title is NOT located in imported data');
}
```

This always returns "Title is located in imported data" even when the title isn't present in the table. I'm assuming I'm incorrectly using :contains?

Comment: It's always return `true` because a `jQuery` selector is true, try to test with `$("table.waffle td div:contains(matchTitle)").length`. To understand try this : `console.log( !!$("table.waffle td div:contains(matchTitle)" )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - find table row containing table cell containing specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135665/jquery-find-table-row-containing-table-cell-containing-specific-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The selector `"table.waffle td div:contains(matchTitle)"` is looking for a `div` that contains the string "matchTitle" - not your variable by that name. Make sure the original variable is included by concatenating it: `"table.waffle td div:contains(" + matchTitle + ")"`
2. A jQuery selector will return true regardless - you need to check the `.length` of that result to see if 1 or more elements actually match the selector.

Here's a fixed demo:

```js
//First create a variable of the product title
var matchTitle = $('h1.font-product-title').text();

//Double check the element is targeting correctly
console.log(matchTitle);

if ($("table.waffle td div:contains(" + matchTitle + ")").length) {
  console.log('Title is located in imported data');
} else {
  console.log('Title is NOT located in imported data');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="font-product-title">220 foo string</h1>

<table class="waffle">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>1</div>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div>220 foo string</div>
      </td>
      <td>£17.98</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div>2</div>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div>330 foo string</div>
      </td>
      <td>£18.98</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```